# To find minimum of ith digit of 4 elements

Tags: java

Given a four n-digit integer ith digit of pin is generated by finding a minimum of ith digit of 4 integer

I have tried to take each ith digit of the number and comparing with other ith digit of number and minimum of the ith digit bof number

```java
import java.util.*;
class EncryptByPin{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many number of digit number you want to print? ");
        int n=sc.nextInt();

        int num1=sc.nextInt();

        num1=NoofDigits(num1,n);

        int num2=sc.nextInt();

        num2=NoofDigits(num2,n);

        int num3=sc.nextInt();

        num3=NoofDigits(num3,n);

        int num4=sc.nextInt();

        num4=NoofDigits(num4,n);
        int pin=Generatepin(num1,num2,num3,num4);


System.out.println("Pin is:"+pin);}

private static int NoofDigits(int num,int l)
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

int a=num;

    int length=String.valueOf(a).length();

while(length>l || length<l)

{   System.out.print("Sorry we cannot proceed reenter the number as per 
length");

    a=sc.nextInt();

    length=String.valueOf(num).length();
}

sc.close();

return a;
}

private static int Generatepin(int n1,int n2,int n3,int n4)

{int i=0;int sum=0;int q;

while(n1>0)

{

q=Math.min(n1%10, Math.min(n2%10, Math.min(n3%10, Math.min(n4%10, n1%10))));

sum=(int) (sum+q*Math.pow(10,i));

i++;

n1=n1/10;

n2=n2/10;

n3=n3/10;

n4=n4/10;}

return sum;

}
}
```

I expect the output to be
n=4

1st number: 6373

2nd number 7383

3rd number 8362

4th number 7383

pin        6362

Error
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)

at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)

at EncryptByPin.main(EncryptByPin.java:9)
```

Comment: Don't create a new `Scanner` inside `NoofDigits`, and then close it. When you close it, you close `System.in` and all `Scanner` objects on `System.in` will now fail. Only create one `Scanner` on `System.in`, and don't ever close it, since closing System.in is not your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is a little bit of overkill for the problem case.I've written a similar code which I assume is simpler.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SOF {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the value of n (digits)");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s1.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
    String num1 = s1.nextLine();
    String num2 = s1.nextLine();
    String num3 = s1.nextLine();
    String num4 = s1.nextLine();
    System.out.println(FindPin(num1, num2, num3, num4, n));
}

public static String FindPin(String num1, String num2, String num3, String num4, int n) {
    String pin = "";
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pin += Integer.toString(Math.min(Math.min(Character.getNumericValue(num1.charAt(i)),Character.getNumericValue(num2.charAt(i))),Math.min(Character.getNumericValue(num3.charAt(i)),Character.getNumericValue(num4.charAt(i)))));
    }

    return pin;

}}
```

Let me explain.I passed 4 numbers to the "FindPin" function that returns the pin value.The for loop scans the iTH digit if each number and sends them to "Math.min" function that returns least of numbers.This number is attached to the string.Similarly the loop runs for such n digits and returns the pin value.

I'm a beginner in field of java programming too and I hope you liked my approach.